# Embedding html tags inside rails tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to embed html tag inside rails tag but they are not working .I am even using it with html_safe still they are not working.Here is my code

```
<li class="blue">

                              <span>
                              <%= link_to "#{if user.status == "Active"
                               then "Status Change"
                                '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>'
                                else "Status Change"
                                  '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>'
                                 end}","/users/change_status?id="+user.id.to_s %>

                              </span>
                            </li>
```

I am not getting the desired output .It is printing

> <`i class="fa fa-eye">

this on the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<li class="blue">
  <span>
    <%= link_to "/users/change_status?id=#{user.id}"  do %>
      <% if user.status == "Active" %>
        Status Change <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
      <% else %>
        Status Change <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
</li>
```

and, for

```
<%= link_to "/users/change_status?id=#{user.id}" do %>
<% end %>
```

part, you can use something like this:

```
<%= link_to change_status_users_path(id: user.id) do %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Glad it helped. I just figured that when user.status equal or not equal to  "Active", the content does not change, these should be something more to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the [block notation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

```
<%= link_to 'Status Change' do %>
  <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
<% end %>
```

I removed the conditionals to make my point clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 'Status Change <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>'.html_safe
```